# How to change background color of a specific 'td' element having no id/class, when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on a large table (say 100*100) in HTML. So, unable to provide every element its id/class. And I want to change the bg color of the cell which is clicked (by means of javascript). How would I know which cell is clicked or please suggest me any other alternative to do the same.

Comment: in jQuery, if you put a event listener on the `td`, it will be `$(this)`

Comment: Share some efforts please

Comment: `$("table").on("click", "td", function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` to get the clicked element inside the click callback, and then use `.css` to change its background color.

```js
$("td").click(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set an handler on the `table` and capture the `click` event via event delegation during [the bubbling phase](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). This will avoid to set an handler on each cell of the table, which can be really expensive especially when the table has a lot of cells (as in your specific scenario).

**Javascript**

```
let table = document.querySelector('table'); 
/* or other selector retrieving the table */

table.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   let tgt = ev.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
   if (tgt === 'td') {
      tgt.classList.add('selected');
   }
});
```

With this script a `.selected` class will be applied once to the cell that received the click event. The choice to use a classname instead of setting an inline style allow you to keep off the style from the javascript, so your code can be more mantainable.

**CSS**

```
.selected {
   background: yellowgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
        $(this).siblings().css("background-color", "transparent");
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("table").find("td").css("background-color", "transparent");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
    <td>Col 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```